# What is the magnitude of the sound that a Helmholtz Resonator attenuates?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, acoustics, resonance

I know that the shape of the Helmholtz Resonator, specifically its neck shape and the volume of its cavity, determine the resonance frequency of the resonator. Moreover, the resonance frequency is given by the following equation:

$$
f_r = \dfrac{c}{2\pi}\sqrt{\dfrac{A_n}{V_c~L}}
$$

Where $f_r$ is the resonance frequency, $c$ is the speed of sound, $A_n$ is the cross-sectional area of the neck, $V_c$ is the volume of the cavity, and $L$ is the equivalent length of the neck.

The equation shows that many different resonator shapes can have the same resonance frequencies. So why would one chose one shape over another for attenuation a given frequency? Does the shape of the resonator also affect the magnitude of attenuation? How?

What determines the magnitude of sound attenuation caused by the resonance of the resonator?

I think that the amplitude of the incident sound wave is partially responsible for the magnitude of the attenuation but is it also dependent on the shape of the resonator? What is the relation?

How would one design a Helmholtz Resonator to attenuate a tone of a given frequency and magnitude? How does the size of the resonator affect the magnitude of sound attenuation?